# Why do certain keys sound good together?

Tags: scales, harmony, key, mixing, dj

I am a DJ and the software I dj with just introduced key analyzation (Serato DJ). So now I have the key to every song in my library. Someone invented a way for DJ's to mix music in key without having to memorize classical keys. It's called a Camelot Wheel. (MixedinKey.com)[image]

The way it basically works is: mixing songs immediately to the left or right or up produces a good harmonic mix. So, if you're playing a song in Ab minor (1A), it'll sound good with 12A, 2A or 1B.

**So, my question is why do certain keys sound harmonically good together?**

**Why does, say, Ab Minor sound good with either Db Minor or Eb Minor?**

P.S.: I am grad student in mathematics so I'd prefer if you can get technical mathematically. Not necessary though.

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14291/what-is-harmonic-mixing-mix-in-key may be relevant.

Comment: This is nearly identical to this: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32774/how-are-keys-in-the-circle-of-fifths-related

Comment: This is very bad. E Majors relative key is c# minor not Db. B Major's relative minor is G# minor not Ab

Comment: @NeilMeyer I thought C# and Db the same. No?

Comment: @AlJebr nope see http://music.stackexchange.com/q/2/7222 and http://music.stackexchange.com/q/23976/7222

Comment: B Major and E Major are both keys without a single flat in them. There relative minors would not start on notes that the form no part of the Major keys they are based on.

Comment: Actually, 12, 1 and 2 are all technically wrong. And if a song was flagged up AS Gb, or C#, what does a D.J. do? But - to a D.J., does it really matter? They could have just put the colours, or x,y,z.

Comment: @Tim Why are 12, 1, and 2 wrong?

Comment: When the  major key is sharp, then the relative minor key is also sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the smallest harmonic changes.  When you move radially none of the notes in the scales change (A minor has the same set of notes as C major), even though the tonal centre does.   The set of notes in the scale stays fixed while the nature of the tonality changes between major and minor.  Thus there is a similarity or continuity in the tone of the music under this kind of change. The "left/right" changes are also small changes in key: the two keys differ by only one note, and that note is only changed by a half step; e.g. going from C major to G major only the note f changes to f#.  So again, there is a high degree of similarity between the set of notes in these two keys.  Note that under this kind of change the major/minor nature of the tonality is held fixed while one of the notes change.

This is [the circle of fifths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_fifths) (up to the formal errors noted in the comments to the OP), and memorizing it is, in my opinion, is basically the same as "learning the classical keys".

Comment: a minor has a G#?

Comment: @NeilMeyer I'm interpreting minor as natural minor

Comment: @NeilMeyer - a change up or down a fifth seems acceptable, with just one note difference, so I suppose the (sometimes) one note difference between relative major /minor will also be acceptable. It always has been. Sadly, the 'wheel' has no mention of parallels, though...